# How to construct query that counts results based on column value being unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query below which works fine but multiple records from the same member get counted in numField1. How would I change it so that numField1 only counts 1 record per member per position but still groups them as it currently does? In the table the member is in a column named memberId.

`SELECT *, COUNT(field1) AS numField1, AVG(price1) FROM tableName GROUP BY field1, position HAVING  status = '1' ORDER BY numField1 DESC, updated DESC`

Edit: Perhaps this will help, I want to know how many records each unique pairing of field1 and position there are counting records that match by the same memberId only once.

```
recordId | memberId | status | updated | field1 | position | price
==================================================================
    1         55        1         1      apple       1       1.00
    2         55        1         2      apple       1        .50
    3         65        1         3      apple       1        .75
    4         75        1         4      apple       2       2.00
    5         85        1         5      apple       2       3.00
    6         95        1         6      apple       2       4.00
```

The expected output would be a count of 2 for apple with position 1 since only two unique memberIds contain apple and position of 1 and count of 3 for apple with position 2 since three unique membersIds contain apple with position 2. Original query counts 3 for each since it counts records with the same memberId, field1 and position multiple times. Relevant expected results below, hope this helps.

```
field1 | position | numField1
==============================
apple        1       2
apple        2       3
```

Comment: It is not explained clearly enough, please can you show some example data - just a few rows - and an example output from that data.

Comment: Added some example data/output to post.

Comment: Why `HAVING  status = '1'` and not `WHERE status = 1`?

Comment: That was a mistake, appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one result row per `field1` + `position`, so group by them. For each such combination you want the count of distinct `memberID`, so count distinct `memberID`.

```
select field1, position, count(distinct memberid)
from tablename
group by field1, position
order by field1, position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 'DISTINCT' ?

```
SELECT *
,COUNT(DISTINCT field1) AS numField1
,AVG(price1)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY field1
    ,position
HAVING STATUS = '1'
ORDER BY numField1 DESC
    ,updated DESC
```

Comment: Tried that but numField1 is equal to 1 even when there are multiple records with the same field1 from different memberId. If it makes any sense, I only want to count them once per different memberId. So if 3 records have a field1 value of apple, and two of the records are by the same memberId, it should return 2.